# closed subset that has the same size

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $\psi(A)>0$ where $\psi$ is some measure and $A$ is an open set. Is it true that we can always find a closed set such that $B \subseteq A$ and $\psi(B)=\psi(A)$?

I have a follow up question here (what if I change the question to $\psi(B)>0$ instead of $\psi(B)=\psi(A)$):
[Existence of closed subset of positive measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2634448/existence-of-closed-subset-of-positive-measure)

Comment: If the measure is regular, then you can find a closed set $B$ such that $\psi(B)>\psi(A)-\varepsilon$ or instead you can find an $F_\sigma$ set with the same measure of $A$. ($F_\sigma$ - countable union of closed sets - note that any open set is $F_\sigma$ so maybe this comment is irrelevant)

Answer (score 1):

No. Suppose that $\psi$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ and that $A=(0,1)$. If $B$ is a closed subset of $A$, then $\psi(B)<1=\psi(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

No. The reason is that the complement of a closed subset is open and that open sets have a non-zero measure in most of the usual cases.